# wildcard and generic from TreeItem

Tags: java, javafx

I have following class:

```
class TreeItem<T extends TreeItem<?>>{

    private final ObservableList<T> childs;
    private T parent;

    public void addChild(T unit){
        childs.add(unit);
        unit.setParent(this);
    }

    public <T> void setParent(T parent){
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

I get this message on setParent:

> ***Incompatible types.***
>
> **Required:**   T
>
> **Found:**      T

How can i fix this?

Comment: There are 2 different type parameters `T` in your code: One for the class and one for the `setParent` method. The one of the method hides the one of the class for the method body/method parameters. The compiler just recognizes that the method's `T` may not extend the classe's `T` and therefore the `parent` cannot be safely assigned to the `parent` field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rewrite this:

```
public <T> void setParent(T parent){
    this.parent = parent;
}
```

With this:

```
public void setParent(T parent){
    this.parent = parent;
}
```

Also I would suggest to remove the wildcare in the class name declaration, as the code would not compile.

So replace this:

```
class TreeItem<T extends TreeItem<?>>
```

With this:

```
class TreeItem<T extends TreeItem>
```

You have a final variable in your class. So it should be initialized either in constructor or inline. As long as you use generic variable and generic type is resolved when you instantiate a new object, the right way to do is to initialize it in constructor like this:

```
public TreeItem(ObservableList<T> childs) {
    this.childs = childs;
}
```

When you are done with the above proposed changes you may notice that the compiler warns you with the message: `Unchecked call to 'setParent(T)'`. That means that the compiler does not guarantee the code is safe during runtime and possible *heap pollution* may occure.
I will illustrate it with an example. The following code while running ends up with `ClassCastException` as we set `parent` variable with the type which is not `T` (it is possible due to *type erasure*).

```
class ChildTreeItem<T extends TreeItem> extends TreeItem<T> {
    public ChildTreeItem(ObservableList childs) {
        super(childs);
    }
}



public class TreeItem<T extends TreeItem>{

    private final ObservableList<T> childs;
    private T parent;

    public TreeItem(ObservableList<T> childs) {
        this.childs = childs;
    }

    public void addChild(T unit){
        childs.add(unit);
        unit.setParent(this);
    }

    public void setParent(T parent){
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public T getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChildTreeItem<ChildTreeItem> treeItem =
            new ChildTreeItem<>(new ObservableSequentialListWrapper<>(new ArrayList<>()));
        TreeItem<ChildTreeItem> parentItem =
            new TreeItem<>(new ObservableSequentialListWrapper<>(new ArrayList<>()));

        parentItem.addChild(treeItem);
        List<ChildTreeItem> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
        itemList.add(treeItem.getParent()); //<------------------- Heap pollution

        ChildTreeItem childTreeItem = itemList.get(0); //<-------- ClassCastException
    }
}
```

The possible solution to this problem is to not parametrize the variable `parent` but to make it `TreeItem` type:

```
public class TreeItem<T extends TreeItem>{

    private final ObservableList<T> childs;
    private TreeItem parent;

    public TreeItem(ObservableList<T> childs) {
        this.childs = childs;
    }

    public void addChild(T unit){
        childs.add(unit);
        unit.setParent(this);
    }

    public void setParent(TreeItem parent){
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public TreeItem getParent() {
        return parent;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanx a lot, it is running without the wildcar. The final variable childs is initialized in the constructors. It was just for example ;)

Comment: You are welcome =) BTW, fabian comment to your question describes nicely the nature of the initial mistale with incompatible types.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have  define already in your class level of Generic type. It is not clear why you put  before your setParent function. But let's assume you want to define a generic type in function level, then when you call it, you need to specify the type

Ex:

```
TreeItem<String> treeItem = new TreeItem<String>();
treeItem.<String>setParent("something");
```